# .net core EF: remove-migration does not remove migration files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, database-migration

I tried to use database migrations to create an initial table structure and some seeding data for my database. So I created two migrations: InitialCreate and InitialSeed. So far so good, the ModelSnapshot.cs is filled and the migration.cs files are being generated. But now when I add another migration, I can no longer remove it. For example: I changed a minor table and called

```
add-migration test
```

I now have the files 321321321_test.cs and 321321321_test.Designer.cs - so far so good. But when I call

```
remove-migration
```

then those files are no longer removed. There are no error messages, it just doesn't remove anything. This is the package manager console output:

```
PM> remove-migration
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
      No type was specified for the decimal column 'Totalprice' on entity type 'BillSelectEntity'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values using 'HasColumnType()'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.0 initialized 'OphiContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Reverting model snapshot.
Done.
```

Do you have any idea why this might be happening? Is there a place where I can look at the framework itself and see what "remove-migration" actually does so I can try to find the problem? Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems I found the answer to my own question: https://www.ophidia.net/en/remove-migration-doesnt-remove-the-migration-files/

Long story short: the migrations seemed unable to handle a table with default values:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Profession>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("('')"); // this line is the problem
});
```

Thankfully there was only 1 table with a defaultValue, so I removed this line and afterwards it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a 1 layered application or an N-layered application? Have you tried specifying the `context`? Have you tried specifying the `startup project` and/or the `project` where EF is?

This might give you a hint, project called with and `Laboratory.API.csproj` and `Laboratory.Infrastructure.csproj`

**CLI Command** when you stand inside the /api directory:

`dotnet ef --startup-project Laboratory.API.csproj --project ..\Laboratory.Infrastructure\Laboratory.Infrastructure.csproj migrations remove --context LaboratoryContext`

Tree stucture:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── Laboratory.API
|  ├── Application
|  ├── appsettings.json
|  ├── Controllers
|  ├── healthcheck-ui.css
|  ├── Laboratory.API.csproj
|  ├── Program.cs
|  ├── Properties
|  ├── Startup.cs
├── Laboratory.Domain
|  ├── AggregateModel
|  ├── Exceptions
|  ├── Laboratory.Domain.csproj
|  └── SeedWork
├── Laboratory.Infrastructure
|  ├── EntityConfigurations
|  ├── Laboratory.Infrastructure.csproj
|  ├── Migrations
|  ├── LaboratoryContext.cs
|  └── Repositories
```